# In CentOS 5.6, unable to: hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Output from CentOS 5.6:
$ hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers

http authorization required
realm: kforge.ros.org Restricted Area
user:
password:

I keep getting asked for a user name and password. However cloning works fine for other https repos like:
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/aragost/hello

Also works fine from Mac OS X 10.6.7 using MacPorts

Help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10449/in-centos-5.6,-unable-to:-hg-clone-https://kforge.ros.org/openni/drivers/) by [expressoCoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/773/expressocoder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay I figured out what was causing my problem.

First off, the CentOS 5.6 yum repo only has python 2.4, so you will need to manually download and install python 2.6.

Uninstall mercurial if you have previously installed it from the CentOS yum repo, because mercurial would have been installed with python 2.4 files.

Manually download the source for docutils-snapshot and install it for python-2.6. Then download mercurial 1.8.x and install it for python 2.6.

Then anonymous read-only cloning should work

---

Originally posted by [expressoCoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/773/expressocoder/) with karma: 26 on 2011-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1